# Zotero 6 is unable to open pdfs using the default application [Okular]

Tags: permissions, kde, pdf, okular, zotero

I think this is an Ubuntu problem because I am able to do simply double click items on Zotero if my default application is set to native PDF viewer. However, if my default application is Okular, I am not able to double click items in Zotero. I have to navigate to where the PDF is located (*Show file* option in Zotero) and double click to open.

I think the issue is that I have installed Okular using flatpak. This is because the latest version was not available in the Software store (Okular Version 21.12.1).

I followed this video to make a change: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf3VUrDCBJs, but I wasn't able to do this. I also tried to navigate through Zotero to where Okular is installed on my system, but Zotero does not have the permission to go there. Even if I have the permission, I'm not sure what's an equivalent of a `.exe` file that I can just "set" in Zotero.

How do I set the default application to Okular for Zotero 6?

Comment: Hello. I am confused what does an .exe have to do with Zotero.

Comment: Zotero has an option of setting a default pdf via it's menu. However, when I click on custom, it opens up an file dialog box where I can navigate to the installed application. I don't know what's an equivalent of .exe for Ubuntu.

Comment: There is not one. The conclusion I would make is this is a Windows only feature. I suggest you ask the people that make the app how to deal with this. https://forums.zotero.org/discussions

Comment: Nope. I am on Ubuntu and I have Zotero 6 installed. The problem isn't with Zotero... It's just that I am not able to navigate to where Okular is installed on Ubuntu. The custom dialogue box says that I don't have permissions to navigate to that location.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Open Zotero.
2. Go to *Edit* → *Preferences*.
3. Click the dropdown menu on *Open PDFs using* and select *Custom...*

   [image: Zotero Preferences window]
4. In the window that opens navigate to the Okular installation directory, which should be `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.kde.okular/x86_64/stable/active/export/bin`, select the `org.kde.okular` file and press *Open* on the top right of the window.

   [image: Choose Application window]
5. Then close the *Zotero Preferences* window and that's it! You should now be able to double-click on files in Zotero and have them opened in Okular.